# What is the equivalent to locate command in KornShell?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, find, ksh

I am using **KornShell (ksh)** and I need to know what is the command to search a file in the system?

I have used locate in bash looking for a similar one.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "find" command to search for a particular file in the system.
There are various option to search by name,size,time,etc
You can refer to man find for more help.

E.g.
find . -name abc
will search abc file in the current directory and subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

`locate` is not a bash-internal command, it is an external program. Provided that `/usr/bin/locate` is installed and in your `$PATH` environment variable, it should work just the same in `ksh`.

Comment: thanx OrbWeaver. but i don have locate in the path u have mentioned. is there any alternative command to search a file or folder in command?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
which cmdName
```

and/or

```
whence cmdName
```

where of course, you replace cmdName with the command you are searching for.

`which1 will searchs the $PATH variable, while` whence` (if available on your system) searchs $PATH, aliases and functions.

Answer (score 0):

old post but imho still important:

`locate` is not the same as `find`. `locate` keeps a database of filenames, in which it searches for the files. It is therefore faster but less up-to-date than `find`, which browses the actual directories on the fly.